# Use nested select query in a where clausle MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, join

Hello i have a very old and BIG query which gous like this:

```
select id, someValue, (select x from y inner join x on x.y = y.zzz) as filter
```

Now i need to filter for the deliverd variable like

```
select id, someValue, (select x from y inner join x on x.y = y.zzz) as filter
WHERE filter not 'badPractise'
```

Is there any way i can use it without making the same join in the where clausule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `HAVING` clause to filter out with your filter column

```
select id, someValue, 
(select x from y inner join x on x.y = y.zzz) as filter
FROM ....
HAVING filter <> 'badPractise'
```